# C++ UI alternatives in visual studio 2013

Tags: c++, forms, visual-studio-2013

C# is my primary language, I want to learn C++ but with windows form or any GUI, just not console. I read that they took windows form out of visual studio 2013 for C++. Are there any alternatives or workarounds? How are people making UI based C++ programs in vs 2013 now? I found this but it feels like a jerry rigged approach http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/application_visual_studio_2013.php. I would like to use VS 2013 and UI forms somehow.

Comment: Been wanting to know this also. To add to this question, is there any NATIVE C++ windows form alternatives?

Comment: Maybe look at ATL/WTL? That's what google chrome and parts of Visual Studio 2013 use.

Comment: There's a number of open source frameworks. Have a look at WTL, wxWidgets and my personal favorite Qt

Comment: QT looks good, how much is it for commercial use, flat payment or % royalties?

Answer (score 0):

There answer is there is no native solution. You'll need to use an open source framework like Qt, wxWidgets, etc. I would recommend Qt, as it does have an LGPL license option and their form builder integrates within Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Code to gui](https://codetogui.com) which is easy to setup and use with Visual Studio and c++. Although it doesn't gives too many gui features like qt as of now but seems like a great option for learning c++ with basic form builder gui.

PS: It internally uses wxwidgets so you can also re-program it's internally generated files to make complex guis.